# Multiple named MapStruct `AfterMappings` are not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am having issues trying to use two `AfterMappings` using the same target. I have tried using both `@Qualifier` and `@Named` methods along with `@BeanMapping` but with no success: no after mapping would be called.

Here is a code snippet:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class NotificationMapper {
    // ... autowired services

    // ... several @Mappings
    public abstract IssueNotificationResponse notificationToIssueResponse(Notification notification);
    
    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "descOrder")
    public abstract List<IssueNotificationResponse> notificationsToIssueResponsesDesc(List<Notification> notifications);
    
    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "ascOrder")
    public abstract List<IssueNotificationResponse> notificationsToIssueResponsesAsc(List<Notification> notifications);

    @Named("descOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public void afterMappingOrderDesc(@MappingTarget List<IssueNotificationResponse> target) {
        // ... sort target in desc order
    }

    @Named("ascOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public void afterMappingOrderAsc(@MappingTarget List<IssueNotificationResponse> target) {
        // ... sort target in asc order
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to work it out with `@BeanMapping` and `@Named`.

However, I can suggest doing it with an other solution using two distinct [@Context](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#passing-context) you'll use with Mapstruct:

- `ContextDesc`
- `ContextAsc`

Example for the first one:

```
public class ContextDesc {

    public ContextDesc() {
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void establishRelation(@MappingTarget List<IssueNotificationResponse> issueNotificationResponse)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use them with your

- `notificationsToIssueResponsesDesc(List<Notification> notifications, @Context ContextDesc ctx)`
- `notificationsToIssueResponsesAsc(List<Notification> notifications, @Context ContextAsc ctx)`

---

UPDATE: With

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class TmpMapper {

    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "descOrder")
    public abstract IssueNotificationResponse notificationsToIssueResponsesDesc(Notification notifications);

    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "ascOrder")
    public abstract IssueNotificationResponse notificationsToIssueResponsesAsc(Notification notifications);

    @Named("descOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public IssueNotificationResponse afterMappingOrderDesc(@MappingTarget IssueNotificationResponse res, Notification notifications) {
        // ... sort target in desc order
        return res;
    }

    @Named("ascOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public IssueNotificationResponse afterMappingOrderAsc(@MappingTarget IssueNotificationResponse res, Notification notifications) {
        // ... sort target in asc order
        return res;
    }
}
```

You have the `@AfterMapping` generated but it's not what you want because there is no `List` in the parameters. Mapstruct doesn't handle `@AfterMapping` and `@Named` with `Collections` or I didn't find a way do to it. You can check it out with this example

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class NotificationMapper {

    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "descOrder")
    public abstract List<IssueNotificationResponse> notificationsToIssueResponsesDesc(List<Notification> notifications);

    @Named("descOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public List<IssueNotificationResponse> afterMappingOrderDesc(@MappingTarget List<IssueNotificationResponse> res, List<Notification> notifications) {
        // ... sort target in desc order
        return res;
    }

    @Named("descOrder")
    @AfterMapping
    public IssueNotificationResponse afterMappingOrderDesc(@MappingTarget IssueNotificationResponse res, Notification notifications) {
        // ... sort target in desc order
        return res;
    }
}
```

You'll see there is only the method `afterMappingOrderDesc(IssueNotificationResponse res, Notification notifications)` which is generated and used. The `List` one is not used.

Comment: Is there another way? I would like to not modify the signature of the mapping method.

Comment: I've added an example so I don't think you can handle your problem without `@Context`. But, another solution might be to encapsulate your `List<Notification>` into an other object and use `@Mapping( target = "title", qualifiedByName = { "TitleTranslator", "EnglishToGerman" } )`  as shows here https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers. But I would still prefer the `@Context` solution :) You keep your data structure clean this way.

Comment: I will stick with the `@Context` answer. Thanks a lot!